# Average Query Time of Lucene for Huge Document Set

Tags: solr, lucene, sphinx

We want to index 100 million documents with average size of 10 KB on a single 8-core Xeon machine with 32 GB of RAM. The total size of documents is around 1 TB. The set is frozen and there will be no updates. Hence, indexes can be optimized for read-only usage. Most of the queries are simple and a simple algorithm like BM25 is adequate for us.

Has anybody done this before with [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/%E2%80%8E)? If yes would you please tell the performance metrics, like queries per second, index size, and specially mean response time of queries.

I know it depends on the hardware performance and the best way is to test it ourselves, but before we test it I'd like to have others' experiences. Specially, we want below 1 second response times. Is it possible with a single machine and 100 million documents? Is [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) a faster solution? I should mention that we do not want distributed solutions like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/%E2%80%8E). And, I am aware of [Lucene's nightly benchmarks](http://people.apache.org/~mikemccand/lucenebench/) but its set is very smaller (4 millions doc) and the average query time is not reported.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

As always it depends a lot on what queries you are running against the index. For simple keyword search, a 1TByte / 100M document fully optimized index should be quite responsive on a 32GB machine, provided you run the index from a SSD. With spinning drives, not so much.

Our current large-scale index is 3.6TByte / 1.2B documents and response times with 80GB of RAM is below 1 second. It is running on Solr, but performance would be the same or better under pure Lucene. There's a write-up at https://sbdevel.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/terabyte-index-search-and-faceting-with-solr/ which has some performance graphs.